# Cartopy (or is it Matplotlib?) incorrectly plotting points in an upward curve from 0,0

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I'm trying to plot the location of IP addresses as they connected to one of our servers using Cartopy + Matplotlib. I have a CSV containing timestamps, IPs, lats and longs which I'm iterating through and creating a new map for each elapsed minute.

I've been using https://medium.com/udacity/creating-map-animations-with-python-97e24040f17b as a rough guide.

I can generate an individual frame for each minute, i.e. multiple IPs connect within that minute and then they're plotted. They're just not plotted in the right places...

```
def make_ips_map(date, data, ax=None, resolution='low'):
    if ax is None:
        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19.2, 10.8))
        ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(min_latitude=-65,
                                               max_latitude=70))

    ax.background_img(name='BM', resolution=resolution)
    ax.set_extent([-170, 179, -65, 70], crs=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    players = data[data['Timestamp'] < date]

    for ip, ip_data in players.groupby('IPaddress'):
        player_counts = ip_data.groupby(['long', 'lat']).count()

        # Get lists for longs and lats of each player
        index = list(player_counts.index)
        longs = [each[0] for each in index]

        lats = [each[1] for each in index]
        sizes = player_counts['IPaddress'] * 10

        ax.scatter(longs, lats, s=sizes,
                   color='blue', alpha=0.8,
                   transform=ccrs.PlateCarree())
```

...

```
df = pd.read_csv('test_lat_long.csv', names=['Timestamp', 'IPaddress', 'lat', 'long'])
df['Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp'], errors='coerce')

start_date = datetime(2019, 3, 20, 18, 00, 00)
end_date = datetime(2019, 3, 20, 20, 38, 0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(19.2, 10.8))
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.Mercator(min_latitude=-65, max_latitude=70))

# Generate an image for each minute between start_date and end_date
total_minutes = range((((end_date - start_date).seconds)//60)%60)

for ii, minutes in enumerate(total_minutes):
    date = start_date + timedelta(minutes=minutes)
    make_ips_map(date, df, ax=ax, resolution='low')
    fig.tight_layout(pad=-0.5)
    fig.savefig(f"frames/frame_{ii:04d}.png", dpi=100,
                frameon=False, facecolor='black')
    ax.clear()
```

The points are plotted in a curved line starting at 0,0 which extends up and to the right.

I suspect that it has something to do with a mismatch between the projection (Mercator) and transform (PlateCarree) that ax.scatter is using, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

As usually happens when I post a question on SO, about 30 mins later I figure out the solution.

```
longs = [each[0] for each in index]

lats = [each[1] for each in index]
```

...were returning strings. As soon as they were cast to floats, everything started working perfectly.